# extracting data from matlab file in R

Tags: r, matlab, import, extract

It's the first time I deal with Matlab files in R.

The rationale for saving the information in a .mat file type was the length. (the dataset contains 226518 rows). We were worried to excel (and then a csv) would not take them.

I can upload the original file if necessary

So I have my Matlab file and when I open it in Matlab all good.
There are various arrays and the one I want is called "allPoints"
I can open it and then see that it contains values around 0.something.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

What I want to do is to extract the same data in R.

```
      library(R.matlab)
      df <- readMat("170314_Col_HD_R20_339-381um_DNNhalf_PPP1-EN_CellWallThickness.mat")
      str(df)
```

And here I get stuck. How do I pull out "allPoints" from it. $ does not seem to work.

I will have multiple files that need to be put together in one single dataframe in R so the plan is to mutate each extracted df generating a new column for sample and then I will rbind together.

Could anybody help?

Comment: csv with 200k rows should be fine and importing data like that into R is very easy.

Comment: Or use a generic format like `HDF5`.

Comment: What does the output your `str(df)` look like? Probably a weirdly nested data structure. It might help you to look at the object in R-Studio in the environment panel on the right side. Note that if you click something in there the code that would give you this part of the object will appear in the consol.